# Xmarks makes bookmarks disappear

Tags: browser, bookmarks, xmarks

I've been using Xmarks to sync my bookmarks in Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome for some time.

At first it seemed nice to hv all bookmarks sync among these browsers, but now my bookmarks are lost very often. I've spent tens of hours to organize my bookmarks (around 300). When Xmarks' sync function runs, bookmarks disappear!

That happened lots of times. What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same problem, I discovered that it was related to changes in the profiles names directly in [my.xmarks.com](https://my.xmarks.com/).

I have one profile for Chrome and one for Firefox with the same name assigned in my Xmarks settings in each browser.

For some unknown reason the names of the profiles and bookmarks asigned to them changed in [my.xmarks.com](https://my.xmarks.com/), so for solve it, I restore the name, check the bookmarks assignations and go to the Advanced tab in the settings of Xmarks browser extension, next I performed a manual download.

If you have error messages, clic the button Repair bookmarks.